# How Can I run more than one cassandra server in single machine and form one cluster ring?

Tags: cassandra

I would like know is there any way to run multiple Cassandra servers on a single machine, so tall the servers on that machine form one ring (cluster).

Comment: You want to have all the servers on the one computer belong to the same ring?

Comment: Yes, Because I do not have other machine. So, I should use the single machine and form the ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like know is there any way to run the cassandra servers in a single machine ?

There's always a way!

There is an [excellent tool](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) available that allows you to configure a multi-node cluster locally, but it's currently not supported under windows. When you build a cluster and start it, it will configure the ring for you. You can check out the ring using `./nodetool -h 127.0.0.1 -p 7100 ring` after it has started.

**Just a side-note*, the ccm tool starts the cluster as a background process.